# Highlight Current Link Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing this site;

http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp/

And I'm using this code to highlight current links on top right(Scripted, Branded/Commercial), but Non-Scripted does not get highlighted, I think because it's the home page. Is there a way to make it highlighted when I'm on the home page?

```
$(function() {
$(".textwidget a").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    };
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting this is the home page content

```
<span id="homepage-flag" style="display: none" />
```

and then use this code

```
if($("#homepage-flag").length > 0) {
$("#text-2 a").css("color", "red");
}
```